# LibVlc make Anr exception on playIndex()

Tags: android, vlc, libvlc

I create a simple UDP stream app based on [this sample](https://github.com/wass08/VLC-Simple-Player-Android) which has many stream addresses I have two buttons **"next stream"** , **"previous stream"**.
when I click "next stream" libvlc instance going to play next stream address and when click previous stream vice versa. so simple
this is my code

```
 //first time create player,

    releasePlayer1();
    try {

        // Create a new media player
        player1 = LibVLC.getInstance();
        player1.setHardwareAcceleration(LibVLC.HW_ACCELERATION_FULL);
        player1.eventVideoPlayerActivityCreated(true);
        player1.setSubtitlesEncoding("");
        player1.setAout(LibVLC.AOUT_OPENSLES);
        player1.setTimeStretching(true);
        player1.setChroma("RV32");
        player1.setVerboseMode(true);
        LibVLC.restart(getActivity());
        EventHandler.getInstance().addHandler(mHandlerPlayer1);
        holderPlayer1.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBX_8888);
        holderPlayer1.setKeepScreenOn(true);
        MediaList list = player1.getMediaList();
        list.clear();     
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(settings.getPlayer1Address());
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            list.add(new Media(player1, LibVLC.PathToURI(jsonArray.getString(i))), false);
        }
        player1.playIndex(0);        
 ....
```

.

```
 //next click
  next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             player1.playIndex(selectedVideo);
            }
        });
```

when app start it show first url just fine but problem is when I click next I get Anr exception on this line

```
player1.playIndex(selectedVideo);
```

precicly in this line of libvlc Class

```
playMRL(mLibVlcInstance, mrl, options);
```

can anyone help me about that?

Comment: Did you get any solution or alternative yet